# swift tableview with sections cannot use searchbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have created a tableview with searchbar. My dataset looks like the following :

```
    var data : [[ContactObject]] = []
```

Everything is working well but if i'm trying to search it doesnt really work. 
Here is my search method:

```
  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredGroups = self.data[1].filter({(bo:  ContactObject ) -> Bool in
               return bo.name!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            })
    filteredUsers = self.data[2].filter({(bo:  ContactObject ) -> Bool in
        return bo.name!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
     })
    self.filteredData.append(self.myStories)
    self.filteredData.append(self.filteredGroups  )
    self.filteredData.append(self.filteredUsers)
     collectionView.reloadData()
 }
```

i'm adding self.myStories always because its static content in my tableview. To show the suitable data i have extended my cell for item at like the following:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if !isFiltering(){
    if data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name == "Freunde" || data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name == "Interessen (öffentlich)"{
       var cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "selectStory", for: indexPath) as! StorySelectionTableViewCell

        cell1.label.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name
        cell1.select.setOn(false, animated: true)
        cell1.select.tag = indexPath.row
        cell1.select.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSwitch), for: .valueChanged)
        return cell1
    }

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactsTableViewCell
        cell.select.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.thumb.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.thumb.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumb.frame.height/2
        cell.thumb.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.name.text =  data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name
        cell.select.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonPress), for: .touchDown)
        if data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].imageUrl != "" && data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].imageUrl != nil{

            let url = URL(string:  data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].imageUrl!)
            cell.thumb.kf.setImage(with: url)

                }
        return cell

    }else{



        if filteredData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name == "Freunde" || filteredData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name == "Interessen (öffentlich)"{
                var cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "selectStory", for: indexPath) as! StorySelectionTableViewCell

                 cell1.label.text = filteredData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name
                 cell1.select.setOn(false, animated: true)
                 cell1.select.tag = indexPath.row
                 cell1.select.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSwitch), for: .valueChanged)
                 return cell1
             }

                 var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactsTableViewCell
                 cell.select.tag = indexPath.row
                 cell.thumb.layer.masksToBounds = false
                 cell.thumb.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumb.frame.height/2
                 cell.thumb.clipsToBounds = true
                 cell.name.text =  filteredData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name
                 cell.select.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonPress), for: .touchDown)
                 if data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].imageUrl != "" && data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].imageUrl != nil{

                     let url = URL(string:  filteredData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].imageUrl!)
                     cell.thumb.kf.setImage(with: url)

                         }
                 return cell

    }


}
```

and my numbersOfRowsInSection like this:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isFiltering(){
        return filteredData[section].count
    }
return data[section].count
}
```

the result is no matter which word i'm typing in, my third section (self.filteredUsers) is always empty and self.filteredGroups  always complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I think you should not *append* to `filteredData` here:

```
self.filteredData.append(self.myStories)
self.filteredData.append(self.filteredGroups  )
self.filteredData.append(self.filteredUsers)
```

This will make `filteredData` longer and longer, and the `cellForRowAt` only makes use of the first three items. You should instead replace the whole array with the three subarrays:

```
filteredData = [myStories, filteredGroups, filteredUsers]
```

The other thing I noticed is that you are reloading a *collection view* after the three lines above, but the search bar seems to be installed on a *table view*. Maybe you should be reloading the table view instead, or this is a mere typo.

Comment: thank you so much. Could you explain me the difference

Comment: @Silas Your original approach was "add these three arrays to a nested array", whereas I changed it to "replace the contents of the nested array to only three arrays". With your approach, `filteredData` will grow arbitrarily long, as you keep adding things to it.